# handle subfolders after partitions in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, emr

I got my directory structure as follows.

- /data/year=/month=/day=/source1/abc.log
- /data/year=/month=/day=/source2/def.log
- /data/year=/month=/day=/source3/xyz.log

I wanted to create a hive table with year, month, date as partitions but it is complaining about the subfolder 'source1' when I tried to do MSCK REPAIR TABLE.

Create table statement

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE SAMPLE (
  col1            STRING,
  col2            STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (year STRING, month STRING, date STRING)
STORED as ORC
Location "s3n://blah/data/"
TBLPROPERTIES ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");`

MSCK REPAIR TABLE give "unexpected component source1". Any idea how to create an external table without moving files around? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try setting the following property

```
  hive.msck.path.validation = skip (or) ignore
```

in hive-site.xml and then perform 'MSCK REPAIR TABLE' on your table

(refered from  [Hive Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions%28MSCKREPAIRTABLE%29)
under '**Recover Partitions (MSCK REPAIR TABLE)**' section)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. skip did not work but "ignore" worked. I had to look at hive source to find the fix, Refer DDLTask.java, method = msck. Please edit your answer so that I can mark it an answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably this error is because your path contains a folder after your partitions (source2 and source3), I had a similar issue when I forgot a partition in the creation statement.